# Git - Rollback to a particular folder

Tags: git

Let's say at my root folder, I have the following folders:

```
---Folder1
---Folder2
```

I also have 2 users(user1 and user2).

here is a snippet of the commits list:

- user1 made changes to Folder1 and Folder2(2 hours ago  - let's call this v2)
- user2 made changes to Folder1(4 hours ago - let's call this v1)

The problem is that user1 accidentally made changes to Folder1 and I'd like to keep changes made into Folder2(changes made on v2) and only keep changes made into Folder1(from v1).

Is there a way to do this without involving both users?

Comment: Do you want to create a 3rd commit that fixes things **OR** do you want to modify the latest commit (the change originally made by user1) to touch only folder2?...

Comment: A third comment would be a great solution

Comment: then @pratZ's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the commit for which you want to keep the changes for `Folder1`, i.e. user2's commit. Checkout the `Folder1` from the old commit.

```
git checkout <user2's commit> -- /path/to/Folder1/
```

You can now check the diff,

```
git diff --cached
```

Commit the changes,

```
git commit -m 'Reverting Folder1'
```

---

As commented by **TheCodeArtist**,

**The above steps undo ALL changes made to /path/to/Folder1/ after <user2's commit>**

Comment: Just to clarify, the above steps undo ALL changes made to `/path/to/Folder1/` after `<user2's commit>`.

Comment: ...also while we are at it, it a good practice to always use the `-s` flag with a `git commit` to add the `signed-off-by` line to the commit description automatically.

Comment: what should write for the `<user2's commit>`?

Comment: @OmarLahlou do a `git log` and get the sha for the last commit made by user2 (the one you named as v1). Replace `<user2's commit>`  with the commit sha.